# Conditional Expectation for Geometric Brownian Motion

Tags: expected-value, stochastic-processes, lognormal-distribution, brownian-motion, stochastic-calculus

Given a geometric Brownian motion:

$\frac{dZ}{Z} =  \mu dt + \sigma dW$

Is there a closed-form solution to $\mathbb{E}[z_s | (z_s > a)\cap(z_t > b)]$ for $t \geq s$?

Comment: I don't know, is there?